# How do I insert data to Astra DB using GraphQL API?

Tags: datastax-astra, stargate-oss

I am trying to follow this youtube [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g8COh40v2jU&t=66s).

I am getting stuck at inserting the first piece of data. Ania demonstrates it at 20.46 as follows:

```
mutation insertGenres {
  action: insertreference_list(value: {label: "genre", value: "action"}) {
    value{
      value
    },
  }
```

When I try this, I get an error that says:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Validation error of type FieldUndefined: Field 'insertreference_list' in type 'Mutation' is undefined @ 'insertreference_list'",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "classification": "ValidationError"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When I google the error, a lot of responses tell people to use mutations instead of queries - but I've started from a mutation. I would like to know how to resolve the error, but I'd also like to find the skills to improve my search strategy for finding answers.

When I look at the documentation for using GraphQL with DataStax, I see a different format to the write structure, which is as follows:

> insertbook(value: bookInput!, ifNotExists: Boolean, options:
> UpdateOptions): bookMutationResult

It has a colon and a fragment of text after it. It also explicitly states the ifNotExists: Boolean and options. I don't know if there may have been a change to how to use DataStax since the time Ania recorded the tutorial that means it is no longer a current demonstration of how to use the tool, or if there is an answer for this and I just haven't found it yet.

Comment: I found the problem. There is a red dot in the address bar on graphql that says it cant connect to the server. I don't know why - there are no details provided of why. I can see in Ania's video that she has the same error just before she tries to run the mutation, but I don't know what solves that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide details of how you've configured your [Astra DB](https://dtsx.io/2XM1INf) for Ania's [Netflix Clone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g8COh40v2jU) tutorial so I'm going to assume that you've named your keyspace as `netflix`.

It seems as though you haven't followed the instructions correctly and have missed steps. I can replicate the error you reported if I skip at least one of the steps in the tutorial.

In [step 5 of the tutorial](https://github.com/kubowania/netflix-clone-graphql-datastax#5-insert-data-in-the-table-with-graphql), you needed to do the following:

> ✅ In graphQL playground, change tab to now use `graphql`. Edit the end of the URl to change from `system` to the name of your keyspace: `netflix`
>
> ✅ Populate HTTP HEADER variable `x-cassandra-token` on the bottom of the page with your token as shown below (again !! yes this is not the same tab)

### Switch tabs

In order to insert data, you need to switch to the `graphql` tab.

If you try to insert the data in the `graphql-schema` tab, you will get the error you reported.

### Set keyspace

You need to update the URI of your GraphQL playground in the `graphql` tab to use the keyspace name `netflix` instead of `system`. For example:

```
https://db_id-us-west1.apps.astra.datastax.com/api/graphql/system
```

change to:

```
https://db_id-us-west1.apps.astra.datastax.com/api/graphql/netflix
```

If you try to insert data into the `system` keyspace, you will get the error you reported because the `reference_list` table does not exist in that keyspace. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks - I've followed all the steps in the video. I am in the netflix keyspace. I have double checked everything is as shown in the tutorial. Thanks for trying to help. I think I can take from your message that you don't think anything has changed since the time the video was recorded. That at least narrows the scope of things I need to try to investigate. thanks again

Comment: I have done the tutorial exactly as it appears, step by step, and I can confirm it works as advertised. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why - I have been trying variations on this for days- each time trying a new authentication header key. This is about my 10th time trying and this time it worked. I don't understand why - but I'm moving on to minute 21. Thank you.